# how to add complex object to RDF graph using dotnetrdf?

Tags: rdf, dotnetrdf, rdf-xml

I want to create RDF output (here shown as RDF/XML) like this:
...

```
<dct:temporal>
    <dct:PeriodOfTime>
        <schema:startDate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2019-06-06T00:00:00</schema:startDate>
        <schema:endDate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2019-09-28T00:00:00</schema:endDate>
    </dct:PeriodOfTime>
</dct:temporal>
```

I am using dotnetRDF and it works perfectly, however, all the other objects in my graph are simple, which is not the case here.

The object is

```
<dct:PeriodOfTime>
    <schema:startDate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2019-06-06T00:00:00</schema:startDate>
    <schema:endDate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2019-09-28T00:00:00</schema:endDate>
</dct:PeriodOfTime>
```

How do I use dotnetRDF to do this?

I have tried different things like subgraphs and embedded triples - does not produce the expected.

Comment: I`m not sure what you're asking. What is "simple"? Do you mean an XML SimpleType element? Maybe it would be better to show the expected RDF triples in a more triple like syntax, what about N-Triples or Turtle? Just to understand what you want to achieve. So far, your  expected RDF/XML snippet is not self-contained.

Comment: <rdf:Description rdf:about="https://data.gov.dk/dataset/8078991F-8506-4386-BB21-B7A1F7F95F28">
 <rdf:type rdf:resource="http://www.w3.org/ns/dcat#Dataset"/>
 <dct:identifier xml:lang="en">8078991F-8506-4386-BB21-B7A1F7F95F28</dct:identifier>
 <dct:temporal>
  <dct:PeriodOfTime>
   <schema:startDate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2019-06-06T00:00:00</schema:startDate>
   <schema:endDate rdf:datatype="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#dateTime">2019-09-28T00:00:00</schema:endDate>
  </dct:PeriodOfTime>
 </dct:temporal>
</rdf:Description>

Comment: I agree - above the desired output (had to cut into two comments)

Comment: The dct:identifier shown in the above is "simple". Every triple is like that except for the one shown in the question.

Comment: Ok, but can you show ideally in N-Triples or just pseudo triples what you want to express? You have a dataset which has an identifier and now you want to express some temporal dimension. So in RDF world, this would be an intermediate node mostly a blank node then. Sketch in N-Triples: `:dataset dct:temporal _:123 . _:123 schema:startDate 2020-09-10 . _:123 schema:endDate 2020-10-10 .`